# HTTP request fails

Tags: http, arduino

I am trying to make an HTTP request from a micro-controller , the request is successful when I make it to google.com usign its IP (173.194.33.104) , while it fails when I use my server ip
when I put the ip address in the browser it show me a message like this
"Great Success ! Apache is working on your cPanel® and WHM™ Server" and some more info about apache server , I get my ip from the terminal (ping www.xxxxxx.com)
also if I put my ip with the user name in the browser I see my pages in my server (xx.xx.xx.xx/~aymanj/)
I want to make the HTTP request direct to my pages in the server
how can I do that ?

Comment: If your Apache server isn't set up to have a default page, you'll get the default Apache output that you see. Google has implemented their site to return their home page for all their IP addresses. It sounds like you aren't using the full page URL with your micro-processer, but you are in the browser - or at least you dont seem to have reported the results of using "xx.xx.xx.xx/~aymanj/" in both environments.

Comment: @jdh actually I don't understand ,can you clarify your answer please , and why I can see my pages when I go to xx.xx.xx.xx/~aymanj/ while I cant when I go with the ip only without the username

Comment: @jdh and why if I used another username , I see pages for another domain from the domains that I have

Comment: Couldn't post my answer as a comment, see answer space

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are using a browser (like IE, FireFox or Chrome) and that we aren't talking about using network functions from the Arduino. When you put an URL or some IP address in the browser's address control, and then hit enter - the browser parses that string to determine an address. Then based on your network settings, attempts to make a network connection to that address (typically over port 80). One it connects, the next step in the HTTP protococl is to request a single page from that connection. That page is everything after the address. If there  is no page after the address specified, then its just the default "/" or default page. Each web server (Apache, IIS, etc) has options to set up different defaults. Typically that's something like index.html or default.aspx located in the root directory of whereever the web server lives. Extending that, a web server can map other directories to other paths. In your case, someone mapped a directory "/~aymanj" to your username. In that directory, there is probably a file something like "index.html". And when you go to that address without a directory or path, you are requesting the webserver root. Appparently no one has set a default page for it. Hope this helps you get started.